# select all tables from dba_table except list

Tags: oracle, select, query

I'm missing something in my query. I want to select all tables from dba_tables except a list of tables.

For example, show all except HR.DEPT, SCHEMA.TAB

dba_tables:

```
OWNER    TABLE_NAME
------   ----------
HR       DEPT
HR       TEST
SCHEMA   TAB
SCHEMA   NAMES
TEM      TBA
```

Result after query:

```
OWNER    TABLE_NAME
------   ----------
HR       TEST
SCHEMA   NAMES
TEM      TBA
```

Query I tried:

```
select owner, table_name from dba_tables
where (owner != 'HR' and table_name != 'DEPT' )  OR (owner != 'SCHEMA' and table_name != 'TAB' )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select owner, table_name from dba_tables
where (owner, table_name) not in (('HR', 'DEPT'), ('SCHEMA', 'TAB'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `OR`. When the table is `DEPT` of the `HR` schema, the first `AND` condition is false, but the 2nd `AND` condition is true, thus the `OR` results as true and no row is filtered.

Try with `NOT` + `AND`:

```
select 
    owner, 
    table_name 
from 
    dba_tables
where 
    NOT (owner = 'HR' and table_name = 'DEPT') AND 
    NOT (owner = 'SCHEMA' and table_name = 'TAB')
```